# How to retrieve entity keys without materializaing entities?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I need something like this:

```
context.EntitiesDbSet.Keys.Where(predicate);
```

And predicate here is of type `Expression<Func<Entity,bool>>`
The only solution I know for now is to use projections generated via metada analysis.
Are there any simpler methods?

Comment: And what's wrong with projections?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Nothing wrong but requires generating expressions for instantiating EntityKey. Sure, if I code this manually I can use Selec( e => e.Id). But in this situation I know that PK is exactly one column with name Id.

Answer (score 1):

One way I know is through reflection, using KeyAttribute on Entities and search on Entity the property with KeyAttribute. Example:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class MyEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int EntityID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Type myType = typeof(MyEntity);

            var myProps = myType.GetProperties().ToList()
                .Where(prop => prop.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(a => a is KeyAttribute));

            foreach (var element in myProps) {
                Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that would help.